# How to get index of non-zero item in an array and use this index to get another value from another array or list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, indexing, typeerror

I have a project wherein you have to select a non-zero item in an array and get its index. Using this index, you have to find its corresponding value in another array or list.

For example:

```
best_chr = [[1 1 0]] # numpy array
activity = [2, 3, 4]
```

The code looks like this:

```
chosen_act = [activity[item] for item in range(len(best_chr)) if item != 0]
print(chosen_act)
```

What I intend to do is to find the `index` of `non-zero` item/value in `best_chr` [1, 1 for the example above]. Then, using this index, find its corresponding value in `activity`.

```
Expected output:
chosen_act = [2, 3]
```

The problem is, with the code above, I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int32' has no len()
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: code seems incomplete? how is chromosome_best defined? it seems to be a number, not an iterable?

Comment: @mrxra edited my post already, sorry for the mismatch!

Comment: if you use loops you can use normal python list why numpy? and what is the expected output if `best_chr ` has more than one array?

Comment: @komatiraju032 this is just a snippet of the project I am working right now. Some variables used in getting best_chr is in numpy. So i have to match them to avoid best_chr = (array[1 0 1]), for example.

Comment: does `best_chr` always have one array?

Comment: @komatiraju032 yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `zip`:

```
# best_chr.flatten since it looks like 2-d array
[i for i, j in zip(activity, best_chr.flatten()) if j]
```

If you need to use indexing, use [`numpy.flatnonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html#numpy.flatnonzero):

```
[activity[i] for i in np.flatnonzero(best_chr)]
```

Output:

```
[2, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you! I just have a follow-up question, for instances that it is a 1-d array, will flatten still works?

Comment: @Acee Yes indeed :)

Comment: This is noted! Thank you so much, @Chris!